# What is this in html page? How it will support SEO?

Tags: for-loop, seo, meta-tags

```
<link rev="made" href="mailto:test.com">
```

Comment: Please add background information, if you are trying to show use a code sample press the code sample button in the editor

Comment: Also you might want to take this to http://gamesearchengines.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

It is a way to add semantic information to a page. In this case the email address of the maker.

The value `made` is not in the HTML spec as a [link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-links), so this appears to really be informational only.

The `rev` attribute is supposed to be a link back to a parent page (or previous page), it is short for "reverse link".

Read about the `rev` attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_link_rev.asp) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.3.1).

In terms of SEO, I don't believe this example will make a difference.

Comment: +1 It will probably help SEO freaks spam the webmaster though :/